# How to call an added image in android?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, view

I have written some code. I have 4 images to be called. However only three images are running in the emulator.

The other image is not visible.

Please let me know why the image is not being called correctly?

```
package com.mobility.visiontest.ui;

import com.mobility.visiontest.R;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class DuoChromeTest extends UIScreenActivity {

    private boolean isLeftEye = false;
    private boolean isRightEye = false;
    private int correctAnsCount = 0;
    private int tapCount = 0;
    private int testCount = 1;
    private int images[] = {R.drawable.d1,R.drawable.d2,R.drawable.d3,R.drawable.d4,R.drawable.dc1};
    private int dtest_image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.duochrome_image);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(dtest_image);
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
       {@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           resetView();

       } });
    }



    public void resetView(){
        setContentView(R.layout.duochrometest);
        setObjects();
        int a[] = { R.id.leftEye, R.id.rightEye };
        setOnClickListener(a);

                }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.leftEye:
        case R.id.rightEye:
            resetTestView(R.layout.duochrome_layout);
            break;
        case R.id.option1:
        case R.id.option2:
        case R.id.option3:
        case R.id.option4:
            ++tapCount;
            if(v instanceof Button){
                Button button =(Button)v;
            if(button.getText().equals(getString(R.string.clearBoth) )||
                    button.getText().equals(getString(R.string.yes))){
                ++correctAnsCount;
            }
            }
            updateQuestionandAnswers();
            break;
        case R.id.testagain:
            ++testCount;
            resetView();
            break;
        case R.id.backtoTests:
            backToTests();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }



    private void resetTestView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void backToTests() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.tests));
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }



    private void updateQuestionandAnswers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(tapCount == 3){
//          TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.question)).setText(R.string.duochromeQuestion2);

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.option1)).setText(R.string.clearRed);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.option2)).setText(R.string.clearGreen);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.option3)).setText(R.string.Notvisible);

            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.option4)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else if(tapCount > 3){
            showResult();
        }else{

            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(images[tapCount]);
        }
    }

    private void showResult() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
setContentView(R.layout.duochrometestresult);

        int a[] = { R.id.testagain, R.id.backtoTests};
        setOnClickListener(a);

        String result = null;
         if(correctAnsCount < 4 ){
            result = getString(R.string.duochromeResult2);
            if(testCount == 2 ){
                result = getString(R.string.duochromeResultIteration1);
                ((Button)findViewById(R.id.testagain)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                testCount =1 ;
            }
        }else if( correctAnsCount == 3){
            result = getString(R.string.duochromeResult1);
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.testagain)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.atresult)).setText(result.replace("%d", String.valueOf(correctAnsCount)+"/3"));
            correctAnsCount = 0;
            tapCount = 0;
    }


    // Resets the vision acuity test view
        private void resetTestView(int layout) {
            setContentView(layout);
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(images[tapCount]);
            int a[] = { R.id.option1, R.id.option2, R.id.option3, R.id.option4 };
            setOnClickListener(a);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setObjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    // Back to MainMenu.
    private void backToMain() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.tests));
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // super.onBackPressed();

        AlertDialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Add the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK button
                        backToMain();
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.exitTest));
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in `if(tapCount == 3){` condition you are not using

```
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageResource(images[tapCount]);
```

now it will be changing only stings but not showing image 4